# AppEngine Datastore to LowerCase function - JPA app

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I have a JPA query below:

```
SELECT p FROM Profile p  WHERE  lower(p.country) LIKE 'Philippines%'
```

Does lower function supported by datastore of Google AppEngine? No error or warning, but I think it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since GAE's datastore doesn't support such an operation, it's a fair guess that it isn't supported in the JPA interface

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you're calling lower() before issuing the query, so it should work.  But 'Philippines%' contains an uppercase P, so that won't match anything.